# what is the difference between QCPFinancial and QCPGraph?

Tags: qt, graph, qcustomplot

I have a realtime and big(> milions point) graph.
Which class should i use:  `QCPGraph` or `QCPFinancial`?
What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two different types of graphs. I don't think there is an advantage of one over the other. It depends on what you want to represent in your graph.

[`QCPFinancial`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPFinancial.html#details):

> A plottable representing a financial stock chart.
>   This plottable represents time series data binned to certain
>   intervals, mainly used for stock charts. The two common
>   representations OHLC (Open-High-Low-Close) bars and Candlesticks can
>   be set via `setChartStyle`.

[image]

[`QCPGraph`](http://www.qcustomplot.com/documentation/classQCPGraph.html):

> A plottable representing a graph in a plot.
>   Graphs are used to
>   display single-valued data. Single-valued means that there should only
>   be one data point per unique key coordinate. In other words, the graph
>   can't have loops. If you do want to plot non-single-valued curves,
>   rather use the `QCPCurve` plottable.

[image]

See also [this example](http://qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/simpledemo) for a simple QCPGraph.
Or [this example](http://qcustomplot.com/index.php/demos/financialchartsdemo) for QCPFinancial.